# Rails3 Redirect for javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a form with the `remote => true`. I have a validation that is working correctly.

My problem is when the user enters all the correct information and writes the data at this time I do a redirect to the page of the show. Instead of redirecting, it displays the html of the show in my div. How can I make a javascript redirect that will understand? I did not want to use the `window.location`.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your Update view into an update.js.erb and supply the javascript you wish to return with. i typically use an ajax flash notice as the response.

here is a good walkthrough:
http://www.whatcodecraves.com/articles/2008/12/13/rails_flash_with_ajax/

Comment: oh thanks by reply, but i don't am using the js.erb.
I develop everything in my 'view', how i do the redirect?

Comment: This does not work with rails3 with prototype being out. I'm looking for a solution as well.